# How can I check if a file has forward progress on another branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-merge

Our team is using `git` for version control.

When each team member is assigned a programming task,
they branch off our `dev` branch, and onto their own `issue-#` branch.

With many unmerged issue branches in progress,
how can I evaluate whether a particular file has forward progress, and on what branches?

*Example,*
I would like to checkout the `dev` branch,
and run a command that gives results similar to:

```
dev/issue-34 (20 insertions / 5 deletions)  
dev/issue-71 (60 deletions)
```

for a particular queried file.

---

A command that filters through hundreds of branches, and informs me who has edited a paritcular file thus far.

Answer (score 0):

As a basis, you can use

`git diff --numstat dev origin/issue-34`

to get a list of files with number of new/deleted lines between `dev` and a given issue branch.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use the `git for-each-ref` command to cycle through the branches of interest, then dump out a diff stat on any changes.

In the below script it presumes you are checked out to your dev branch, that you have a remote origin that it is getting the branches from, and that you are in the root directory and are passing in the full path and name of the file of interest.  It also is lacking error checking but should have the basic functionality you need.

```
#!/bin/sh
# $1 is the name of the file we are interested in 
baseSha=$(git rev-parse HEAD:$1)

git for-each-ref  --format="%(refname)" refs/remotes/origin/dev/* | \
while read dev_branch
do
   echo "Checking ${dev_branch}"
   branchSha=$(git rev-parse ${dev_branch}:$1)
   if [ ${baseSha} != ${branchSha} ]
   then
      git diff --stat HEAD..${dev_branch} -- $1
   else 
      echo "No changes"
   fi
done
```